# cakephp3- foreach loop iteration failed

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-3.x

I'm fetching a list of users as an array and paginate the data and show it in the view as a table.

To iterate the array, I use foreach loop. But my foreach loop iteration is not working.

Here's a sample array when I did `print_r()`
I have `id`, `email` and `full_name` fields which I wanna display in view

```
Cake\ORM\ResultSet Object
(
    [items] => Array
        (
            [0] => App\Model\Entity\Role Object
                (
                    [_matchingData] => Array
                        (
                            [Users] => App\Model\Entity\User Object
                                (
                                    [id] => 1
                                    [email] => johndoe@doe.com
                                    [full_name] => John Doe
                                    [[new]] => 
                                    [[accessible]] => Array
                                        (   [*] => 1 )
                                    [[dirty]] => Array
                                        ( )
                                    [[original]] => Array
                                        ( )
                                    [[virtual]] => Array
                                        ( )
                                    [[errors]] => Array
                                        ( )
                                    [[invalid]] => Array
                                        (  )
                                    [[repository]] => Users
                                )
                        )

                    [[new]] => 
                    [[accessible]] => Array
                        ( [*] => 1 )
                    [[dirty]] => Array
                        ( )
                    [[original]] => Array
                        (  )
                    [[virtual]] => Array
                        ( )
                    [[errors]] => Array
                        (  )
                    [[invalid]] => Array
                        (  )
                    [[repository]] => Roles
                )
        )
)
```

This is the part of view where I iterate the array.
Result is stored in `$userList`.
There's always more than one user in this array so I use a foreach loop.

```
<?php foreach ($userList as $user): ?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo($user->id); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo($user->email); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo($user->full_name); ?></td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

In my view, the rows get generated but I don't see the array values. If there are five users in the array, 5 rows are generated but values aren't displayed.
What's wrong with the iteration I used?
Can anyone point out my mistake? 
Thanks!

**UPDATE**

**Controller Function**

```
public function view()
{
    $this->loadComponent('Prg');
    $this->Prg->commonProcess();
    $params = $this->Prg->parsedParams();

    //Listing  members
    $this->paginate = [
    'limit'  => 25,
    'finder' => ['UsersList' =>['filter'=> $params]],
    'extraOptions' =>[
                        'params' => $params
                     ]
    ];

    $usersList = $this->paginate($this->CompanyUsers); 
    $this->set('usersList', $usersList);
    $this->set('_serialize', ['usersList');
}
```

**Model function**

```
public function findUsersList(Query $query, array $options)
{
    $query
    ->select(['Users.id','Users.email','Users.full_name'])
                ->leftJoinWith('Users');
    return $query; 
}
```

Note: This finder function is in `CompanyUsersTable`. `CompanyUsersTable` has relation with users. So I left join `UsersTable` with `CompanyUsersTable` and fetch the list of users under that company.

Comment: Review your `h()` function please.

Comment: h() is a cakephp shorthand for echo. @Praveen Kumar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
<?php foreach ($userList as $user): ?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo($user->_matchingData['Users']->id); ?></td> 
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

OR

Can you share the code that you are using to get the records?

Comment: I've added the controller and finder function. Can you have a look at them? Your answer works but I don't know why _matchingData comes inside the array. @Vivek D.

Comment: I believe that _matchingData should only ever be present when you use the `->matching()` function. That's not shown anywhere here, which leads me to think that you haven't included some key piece of code.